# C++ 11 - rvalue reference variables

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the difference between

```
int a = 42;
```

and

```
int&& rvr = 42;
```

?

`a` is obviously an `lvalue`, but `rvr` is also an `lvalue` since it is a named variable, so can these expressions be considered exactly equivalent, and if not, in which scenarios the `int&&` declaration is preferred?

Comment: Did you read this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228264/use-of-rvalue-reference-and-auto)? It's about `auto`, but the answers there might well clarify your questions.

Comment: http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2008/11/24/rvalue-reference-basics/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They're not exactly equivalent. You're right that both variables are lvalues, but for most types, initialisation of the form

```
T a = b;
```

creates a temporary `T` object, and then constructs `a` from that temporary object. That temporary object may be elided, but it still requires the appropriate constructors to be available.

```
T &&a = b;
```

on the other hand, binds `a` directly to `b`, but requires `b` to be an rvalue. So:

```
int a = 3;
// int&&b = a; // error: && cannot bind to lvalues
int b = a; // okay

struct S { S(const S &) = delete; };
S f();
// S s = f(); // error: no copy or move constructor available
S&&s = f(); // okay
```

And more simply, `decltype` will also give different results for references.

Comment: The use of `[](auto&&x){ f(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)); }` is a practical example of the use of `&&` and `decltype`.

Comment: @Yakk Right, but that's C++14, not C++11. In C++11, `decltype` can be used the same way, but because lambda or function parameters cannot be declared `auto`, this particular pattern doesn't apply.

Comment: Could you explain what does S f(); do there?

Comment: @HaiBi That's just a regular declaration of a function named `f` taking no parameters and returning `S`.

Comment: compared to int&& b = a, auto&& b = a is acceptable, auto&& here means a universal reference, deduced to int&