# why auto doesn't detect reference type of function

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, auto

I made a class with method, which returns reference to member (not good encapsulation). I'm using auto for retuned funtion

```
class classA
{
    public:
    classA(classA & rhs)
    {
        cout<<"copy constr A"<<endl;
    };
    classA() = default;
};

class classB
{
    private:
    classA obA;
    public:
        classA& getRefA(){return obA;}
};

int main()
{
    classB obB;

    auto ob = obB.getRefA();
 }
```

The result is
copy constr A

I understand that auto don't detect reference from function. Is auto detecting only the type without reference?

Comment: Yes. This is how the c++ type deduction works. Scott Meyes did a lot of talks about "type deduction" with auto so you can google for those to get some more information. Or pick up effective modern c++ by him. he has a whole chapter dedicated to this.

Comment: [CppCon 2014: Scott Meyers "Type Deduction and Why You Care"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto` just by itself doesn't infer reference types. You can use `auto&` if you explicitly need a lvalue reference, or `auto&&` to use the reference collapsing rules for type inference.

If you need the type of an expression, use `decltype`. Keep in mind that there is a difference between `decltype(x)` and `decltype((x))` -- the latter preserves references.

More resources on that topic:

- [Universal References in C++11](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)
- [use of rvalue reference and auto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10228264)
- [In C++, what expressions yield a reference type when decltype is applied to them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17241614)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is because `auto` doesn't capture *any* reference. It also won't capture cv-qualifiers.

If you need this behavior, you should use [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).